# Crawl data from next page doesn't change URL

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

i'm trying to change pages in this [site](http://vsd.vn/tin-nghiep-vu-tcph-tv.htm) to crawl information. But it doesn't change URL when I click next page:

My code until now:

```
[...]
paging = response.css('span id.next::attr(href)').extract()
    if paging:
        yield scrapy.Request(paging, callback=self.parse_links)
```

I don't know how to crawl from site like this. Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Network next page request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHZ0W.jpg)
You can try this request for the next page http://vsd.vn/ModuleArticles/ArticlesList/NextPageHDNVTCPH?pCurrentPage=2

This is return next page data